# filtering data on Big number in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, filter, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have some records containing creation time in json format. Before doing actual work on the data I want to filter out data which are created after **31st Dec 11:59:59 PM(1577836740000).** But filter query is not working on such large number. Any suggestion how to filter.

Right now I am doing this is as below.

```
 Dataset<Row> testData = rawDataSet.select(cols)
                .filter(col("name").equalTo("dummy string"))
                ...
                ...//Some filter
                ...
                .filter(col("creationTime").gt((1577836740000l)))
```

Dummy input:

```
 [
      {
        "name": "a",
        "creationTime": 1577836740000
      },
      {
        "name": "b",
        "creationTime": 1577836720006
      },
      {
        "name": "c",
        "creationTime": 1577836710004
      },
      {
        "name": "d",
        "creationTime": 1577836727006
      },
      {
        "name": "e",
        "creationTime": 1577836740040
      },
      {
        "name": "f",
        "creationTime": 1577836740023
      }
      ...
      ...
      ...
    ]
```

Comment: What error are you getting and what is schema of data. I have tried with your data and it is working correctly. Please provide more details.

Comment: The Unix time (1577836740000L) you are using  is not 31st Dec 23:59:59, it is 31st Dec 23:59:00. Use 1577816999 in filter for  31st Dec 23:59:59 which will  not give any value since your display date are before 31st Dec 23:59:59.

Comment: @Nikk My bad it was some caching issue

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code as example

```
import spark.implicits.

val inputData = ( """[{ "name":"vaquar khan","RecordNumber": 2, "Zipcode": 704, "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD", "City": "PASEO COSTA DEL SUR", "State": "PR"},{"name":"Zidan khan", "RecordNumber": 10, "Zipcode": 709, "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD", "City": "BDA SAN LUIS", "State": "PR"}] """);

val inputDataDf = spark.read.json(Seq(inputData).toDS)

inputDataDf.show()

scala> inputDataDf.show
+-------------------+------------+-----+-----------+-------+-----------+
|               City|RecordNumber|State|ZipCodeType|Zipcode|       name|
+-------------------+------------+-----+-----------+-------+-----------+
|PASEO COSTA DEL SUR|           2|   PR|   STANDARD|    704|vaquar khan|
|       BDA SAN LUIS|          10|   PR|   STANDARD|    709| Zidan khan|
+-------------------+------------+-----+-----------+-------+-----------+


inputDataDf.filter("Zipcode  not like '704%' ").show

scala>inputDataDf.filter("Zipcode  not like '704%' ").show
+------------+------------+-----+-----------+-------+----------+
|        City|RecordNumber|State|ZipCodeType|Zipcode|      name|
+------------+------------+-----+-----------+-------+----------+
|BDA SAN LUIS|          10|   PR|   STANDARD|    709|Zidan khan|
+------------+------------+-----+-----------+-------+----------+
```